# Unable to push docker images into AWS ECR from Windows 10

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

When I try to execute this command:

```
> aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1
```

I keep getting the error message:

```
> Unknown options: --no-include-email
```

I followed the instructions here:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html
to update my aws cli to the latest version:

```
> pip install awscli --upgrade --user
```

but the problem persists.
I am completely blocked, as there's no other way that I can use to push my docker images to Amazon ECR.

My environment is the following:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Version 1607
- 64 bits
- aws-cli/1.11.89 Python/2.7.9 Windows/8 botocore/1.5.52
- Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87

Comment: The `--no-include-email` option was added in AWS CLI version 1.11.91

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround which was to just use the regular command:

```
> ecr get-login --region us-east-1
```

And then I removed the part:

```
>...-e none...
```

from the docker login command that was generated and ran it like that and I was able to login into my aws ecr repositories.

Answer (score 1):

If you get rid of the  email option,  you might have a return line including a ''-e none'' that you dont want  you can sed it

```
aws ecr get-login --youroptions | sed 's/\-e none//g'
```

Comment: Which will be a bit tougher on Windows.

Comment: The point was to explain the difference between with or without--no-include-email,  but yeah, indeed